# One model to many controllers - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, cakephp-2.0

Im trying to load one appmodel to many controllers. For example i have appmodel called Item and i want to get some items in HomeController and ContactController. When i execute this code:

```
class HomeController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $items = $this->Item->find('all');
        $this->set('items', $items);
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

How can i get thing from database in many views in CakePHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to declare which model you want to use in your controller.

```
class HomesController extends AppController {
  var $uses = array('Item', 'AnotherModel');

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $uses=array('Item');
```

If using this model in multiple controllers, put this in app controller.